# Save video to 3GP format

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-camera, android-capture

I need to capture the video and video save to the sd card using hardware.camera class.

I created sample application with Camera.callback. It work fine. But saved video not working.

I saved the file in 3gp format. Each byte array added to a single byte array.And it saved to 3gp format.But it is not working.

After i substitute the header and footer portion 3gp in to that file. But it is not working. what i do to record video in this way(hardware.camera)?

Comment: i need to know how save the byte array to video. Received byte array on hardware.callback .How it process ??

Comment: Please be careful when asking your question.  A poorly formatted question is difficult to read, I have edited to make the question more edible for the code monsters.  You should provide some code as @AndrejsCainikovs suggests

Comment: Pixels that come from the camera should go through video encoder. See the answer by @vosmith for the straightforward way to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The Android MediaRecorder class handles recording video withough having to implement the camera callback.  It is capable of saving files in the 3GP format

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html